# How to fix mouseout in explorer, so that it would work

Tags: jquery, explorer

```
$(".test").mouseover(function (ev){
    alery(1);
}).mouseout(function (){
    alert(2);
});
```

This is my code, very simple, but it's not working properly.I tried in IE6,7,8 and the result is the same, just the mouseout alert it's not popuping, why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine on IE ... see my example: http://jsbin.com/azugah

The problem must be somewhere else

Comment: I'm testing it trough IE Tester, can this be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`